# How do I configure my project to push to the corresponding remote branch+

Tags: git, push

when I clone my project I want it to already be configured to push only to the corresponding remote branch to whatever local branch I have checked out.

I have two local branches: develop and master, and two corresponding remotes: remotes/origin/develop and remotes/origin/master.

I know if I checkout develop and set "remote.origin.push" to "HEAD:refs/for/develop" then my changes with go to the right place. But if I check out master it will still want to push to the remote develop branch.

1. How do I set "remote.origin.push" so I don't have to reset it each time I checkout a new branch?
2. How do I add this setting to my project so it's automatically there when I clone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Edit to add TL;DR key to answer: you're probably looking for `push.default`, which you should `git config --global` to whichever of the three settings listed below suits you the most.  See bold bit.

---

As per [git config documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html), you can set `branch.name.remote` to the name of a remote, and `branch.name.pushremote` to override other defaults.  You also have `push.default` to control which branches are pushed if you just write `git push`; and `remote.pushdefault` (overrides one of the branch-specific ones but not the other).  You can also set `remote.remotename.push` to supply a default ref-spec.

This is, admittedly, quite a mess.  But the settings do exist, which handles part (1) (though not with just `remote.origin.push`, you need to use the branch-specific settings).

Part (2), making this happen automatically on `git clone`, is not possible: these configuration items are not part of the repository.  You can get fairly close in one (or both) of two ways:

- Set these for *you*, in your (`--global`) git config file: then they will apply to all repositories, not just this and clones.  This might be acceptable in some situations, but clearly not in all.  **However, you probably *do* want to set `push.default` globally, to `current`, `upstream`, or `simple`** (see the documentation).
- Provide, in the repository you're cloning, a script that invokes `git config` to set all these settings.  Then you need to remember to run the script after each new clone, but at least it's set per repository.